# Docker-compose doesn't resolve DNS to correct service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have two services, `web` and `helloworld`. The following is my docker-compose YAML file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  helloworld:
    build: ./hello
    volumes:
      - ./hello:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 5001:80
  web:
    build: ./web
    volumes:
      - ./web:/usr/share/nginx/html
    ports:
      - 5000:80
    depends_on:
      - helloworld
```

Inside the `index.html` in web, I made a button that opens `http://helloworld` when clicked on. However, my button ends up going to `helloworld.com` instead of the correct service. Both services work fine when I do `localhost:5001` and `localhost:5000`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Where is `index.html` being consumed?  Your local browser?  If so, then `helloworld` is being resolved by your browser, not by either of your containers.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth It is in my browser. However, How would I go and test the application if I don't know the DNS that the micro service will end up residing in? So in deployment, I would have to know first the place that helloworld stays in and then update index.html to the correct DNS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker's embedded DNS for service discovery is for container-to-container networking. For connections from outside of docker (e.g. from your browser) you need to publish the port (e.g. 5000 and 5001 in your file) and connect to that published port.

To use the container-to-container networking, you would need the DNS lookup to happen inside of the web container and the connection to go from web to helloworld, instead of from your browser to the container.

---

Edit: from your comment, you may find a reverse proxy helpful. Traefik and nginx-proxy are two examples out there. You can configure these to forward to containers by hostname or by a virtual path, and in your situation, I think path based routing would be easier. The resulting compose file would look something like:

```
version: "3"

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    command: --docker --docker.watch
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/docker.sock:/var/lib/docker.sock
    ports:
      - 8080:80

  helloworld:
    build: ./hello
    volumes:
      - ./hello:/usr/src/app
    labels:
      - traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/helloworld
      - traefik.port=80

  web:
    build: ./web
    volumes:
      - ./web:/usr/share/nginx/html
    labels:
      - traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/
      - traefik.port=80
```

The above is all untested off the top of my head configuration, but should get you in the right direction. With the PathPrefixStrip rule, you can make a link in web to "/helloworld" which will go to the other container. And since the link doesn't have a hostname or port, it will go to the same traefik hostname/port you are already using.

Comment: So if the container was php or even a django, then I would just access the API from inside php/django, get the data, then serve the template correct? Instead of doing it inside the html file?

Comment: Yes, from container to container you can connect via the container name to access the API's of the other containers.